# SAML - Multiple Service Provider instances connecting to one IdP application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I have an unusual scenario for SSO of a SaaS application. It is a Java/Spring/Spring-SAML webapp. I would like to introduce a 2nd SAML SSO IdP to my WebApp and have one IdP for client accounts, one IdP for support accounts.

As in overview, we've got many single-tenant server instances (client1.acme.com, client2.acme.com, etc.). These are different tomcat instances on different physical servers. Each server can be configured for SAML SSO for client user accounts via Spring-SAML. Typically this connects to MS AD.

This works fine, but now I would like to configure a 2nd IdP in each server to control access for our support staff. This 2nd IdP would be MS AD or Google Workspace. I would like to configure only one application in my IdP all all instances.

Is this even possible? I know that I can easily configure multiple IdPs with Spring Security. But each of my server instances would have a different SAML EntityID and URL, so is it even possible to map these to one application in the IdP?

Any thoughts or approaches welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your scenario correctly, it may be better to keep the IdPs setup separate from your code. There are different ways to connect/federate different IdPs into a designated one which can be used as a single access point, delegating the authentication to the connected IdPs. For example, you may try ADFS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/understanding-key-ad-fs-concepts) or even Keycloak in this role.